# regex single digit

Tags: r, regex

I have a question which I think is solved by regex use in R.

I have a set of dates (as chr) which I would like in a different format (as chr).

I have tried to fool around with the below examples where the first (new_dates) gives the right format for months 1-9 and wrong for 10-12 and (new_dates2) gives the right format for 10-12 but nothing for 1-9.

I see that the code in the first case matches a single digit twice for 10-12, but don't really know how to tell it to match only single digit.

The final vector of correct dates shows the result I would like.

```
dates <- c("1/2016", "2/2016", "3/2016", "4/2016", "5/2016", "6/2016", "7/2016", "8/2016", "9/2016", "10/2016", "11/2016", "12/2016", "1/2017")
new_dates <- sub("(\\d)[:/:](\\d{4})","\\2M0\\1", dates)
new_dates2 <- sub("(\\d{2})[:/:](\\d{4})","\\2M\\1", dates)
correctdates <- c("2016M01", "2016M02", "2016M03", "2016M04", "2016M05", "2016M06", "2016M07", "2016M08", "2016M09", "2016M10", "2016M11", "2016M12", "2017M1")
```

Comment: I myself am a proponent of regular expressions, but would generally advise against their use in the context of dates and time. There are much more robust functions in dedicated packages such as `lubridate` for such tasks.

Comment: Here's a base R method that will return the desired format: `format(as.Date(paste0("1/",dates), "%d/%m/%Y"), "%YM%m")`.

Comment: With regex, you can do it, but with `gsubfn`: `gsubfn("(\\d{1,2})/(\\d{4})", function(x,y) paste0(y, "M", ifelse(nchar(x)==2, "", "M"), x), dates)
`

Comment: The solution proposed by Imo seems to work perfectly. Can I accept it as an answer somehow?

Comment: @lmo Will you post the answer or let know if there is a duplicate?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I spent 5 minutes looking for a dupe and was not successful, so I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base R method that will return the desired format:

```
format(as.Date(paste0("1/",dates), "%d/%m/%Y"), "%YM%m")
[1] "2016M01" "2016M02" "2016M03" "2016M04" "2016M05" "2016M06" "2016M07" "2016M08" "2016M09"
[10] "2016M10" "2016M11" "2016M12" "2017M01"
```

The idea is to first convert to a Date object and then use the `format` function to create the desired character representation. I pasted on `1/` so that a day is present in each element.

Answer (score 0):

As @a p o m said it might be better to look for another solution if you are manipulating dates but if you want to stick with regular expressions you can try this one.

`([02-9]|1[0-2]?)[:\/](\d{4})` [example](https://regex101.com/r/JrrGl3/1)

Comment: I just tried that, and there are two problems. First of all some of it is not usable in R notation. I fixed those myself (I think) but it lacks zeros in front of 1-9. That might of course be related to the R problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dates <- sub("(\\d{1,2})\\/(\\d{4})","\\2M0\\1", dates)

It's fine.
```

Comment: That one gives zeros in front of 10-12 as in: 2016M012.

Comment: I'm sorry,i've mistaken the data.  This code would be fine  `new_dates <- sub("(\\d{2})\\/(\\d{4})","\\2M\\1", sub("(^\\d{1})/","0\\1/",dates))`